# Django and extract IPTC from images

Tags: html, django, python-imaging-library

Maybe a stupid question, but how can I extract information from the image, such as description, headline and keywords using Django & Pillow?

I have this now, but it dont work at all.. Can you help me to fix this or help me with a solution? I can see the IPTC information in photoshop and other software, but i cant see it if upload the images in my django project.

```
def extract_iptc_data(image_file):
    print("Extracting IPTC data...")  # Add this print statement
    # Open the image file
    img = PilImage.open(image_file)
    
    # Initialize title, description, and keywords
    title = None
    description = None
    keywords = []

    # Extract XMP metadata
    xmp_data = img.info.get("xmp", b"")
    print("XMP Data:", xmp_data)  # Print XMP metadata for debugging
    
    if xmp_data:
        # Parse XMP metadata
        xmp_tree = ET.fromstring(xmp_data)
        
        # Find headline (title), keywords, and description
        for elem in xmp_tree.iter():
            if elem.tag.endswith("Headline"):
                title = elem.text
            elif elem.tag.endswith("Keywords"):
                keywords.extend(elem.text.split(","))
            elif elem.tag.endswith("Description"):
                description = elem.text

    return title, description, keywords
```